# Efficiently match many regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

In one of my programs I had to check whether a line matches one of some 20000 regex expressions.

I tried putting the regex into a long chain of `"something1|something2|...something20000"`, or making a list of `20000` regex expressions and running a for-loop over it. I have been using the standard re library. In most cases I have to wait ~20 seconds for the match to finish. I am wondering if there is a faster way, provided that the regexes cannot be simplified or combined easily.

Comment: Can you provide a few samples of these 20,000 regex? And what you’re matching on?

Answer (score 0):

It just an idea. grouping regex.
for example, suppose that regex_groupn matches a common expression of `regexn1, regexn2, ... regexnm` for nth group.
Then you can match `regex_group1|regex_group2|...|regex_groupn`.
If kth group is matched, find matches for `regexk1|regexk2|...|regexkm`.